# Mediaoverlayを含む固定レイアウトEPUBの 音声が再生されない

Tags: epub

Mediaoverlayをサポートする固定レイアウト、いわゆるフィックス型のEPUBを作成しようとしています。しかし、期待どおりに機能しません。知見があれば原因と対策をご教示ください。
以下に、私がこれまでに行った仕事と直面している問題について説明します。

実施した手順:

1. InDesignを使用して、1ページのコミック上に各セリフの画像を追加しました。
2. InDesignを使用してEPUBをエクスポートしました。
3. audioフォルダーを作成し、その中にmp3ファイルを格納しました。
4. XHTMLファイル上でIDとmp3ファイルをリンクし、各ダイアログの音声の開始時刻と終了時刻を指定したSMIL ファイルを準備しました。
5. OPFファイルのタグ内の各項目を指定しました。
6. 7zipを使用してすべてのファイルを圧縮し、拡張子を.epubに変更しました。

確認した問題:

- Adobe Digital EditionsでEPUBファイルを開きましたが、音声が再生されませんでした。
- Thorium ReaderでEPUBファイルを開きましたが、音声が再生されませんでした。

試した解決策:

- xhtml上でalt="代替テキスト"と入力すると、Thorium Readerで開いた際に、各セリフの画像に「代替テキスト」というフレーズを再生することがわかりました。

注記：
作成したファイルとEPUBファイルをGitHubにアップロードしました。
https://github.com/ricky0web/mediaoverlay_fix